# True & False Boolean in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
bear_moved = False 

while True: 
    next = raw_input("> ") 

    if next == "take honey": 
        dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.") 
    elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved: 
        print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through." 
        bear_moved = True 
    elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved: 
        dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.") 
    elif next == "open door" and bear_moved: 
        gold_room() 
    else: 
        print "I got no idea what that means.
```

This is to show my understanding of Boolean. In the line testing `next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved`, if my input is `taunt bear`, the result is `True and True`, which will continue the loop.

So what confused me is line testing `next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved`. If my input is `taunt bear`, is it suppose to be `"taunt bear" == "taunt bear"` and `bear_moved` which is `True and True`? which means the loop will continue instead of cancelling it.

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do?

Comment: you have no loop exit condition, even if you call gold_room you are still in this rooms loop

Comment: Your loop is never cancelled; it always continues.

Comment: Aside: [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) is the name of a very handy Python built-in function, so it's not a good name for a variable.  (Plus it's not very descriptive anyhow.)

Answer (score 0):

`while True:` will continue indefinitely (unless you put in a `break` - usually `break` is bad design in languages like Python)).

You probably want to do:

```
while something == True: #Or - as has been pointed out, `while something` - which is equivalent and more Pythonic
    ...
    some code which eventually sets something to False
    ...
```

Comment: Unless you add in break; - when you put "break;" without quotes in the code, it will end the loop.

Comment: `something = True` is wrong (thats an assignment). `something == True` is considered bad. `something is True` is okayish.  `something` is most correct

Comment: @MikeVella Why is `break` bad design?

Comment: @mr2ert a function should ideally have one entry and one exit point. Some say that `break` statements have their place - but IMO they're usually the sign of fundamentally bad design.

Comment: thanks everyone for sharing your opinion. I think I realized where my problem is. The truth is I don't really get the idea of indentation in python. Special thanks to Martijn Pieters for editing my messy code.

Answer (score 0):

`elif` in python is equivilent to `else if`. If one of the `elif` blocks execute, none of the others can, and will jump to the bottom of the `if`.

After `next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved` is executed and evaluates to true, and the block executes, control of the program continues back at the front of the loop and will ask for input again.